# Find $k$ non-disrupting paths from $s$ to $t$

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, network-flow

Given the bidirectional graph $G = (V, E)$ where $V$ = set of Vertices, $E$ = set of Edges; given source node $s$ and destination node $t$. Let $A_i$ ($i = 1, 2,\ldots l$) be the subset of vertices which is not necessarily connected. $k$ is also given.

Non-disrupting path definition: One subset can be used only once for all paths. But source and destination can use it all the times.

Q. Does there exist $k$ non-disrupting paths from $s$ to $t$? Which algorithm I can use to solve this problem and how can I do? Can you give any example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For $k=2$ and $A_i = V$ there is a specialized algorithm called [Suurballe's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suurballe%27s_algorithm).

For a generic $k$ and $A_i=V$, consider the following single-commodity min-cost network flow problem. On your graph $G$, introduce a capacity vector $U=\{u_{ij}\}$ associated with each edge $(i,j)$. Set each $u_{ij}=1$. Set the cost $c_{ij}$ of traversing an arc $(i,j)$ equal to $1$. Create a commodity with demand $k$ at the destination $t$ and supply $-k$ at the origin $s$. Set up an optimization problem where the goal is to minimize the transportation cost of the commodity, subject to the flow balance constraints at each node and restrict the flow variables to be binary decision variables. Since the capacity is at most $1$, your solution, given by the flow variables corresponding to which arc is used, will consist of $k$ edge-disjoint paths.

For the case when $A_i \subset V$ we tweak $G$ a little. For each node $v \in A_i$ we create a clone $v'$ and create an arc $(v,v')$ with a cost of $0$ and a capacity of $1$ (this ensures that each vertex in $A_i$ is used once during the transportation part). Denote by $V'= A_i \cup \{s\} \cup \{t\} \cup \{ \text{all } v'\} $. Finally, set $E' = \{(i,j)|i \in V' \lor j \in V' \}$, the set of all edges that touch at least one vertex in $A_i$. Now solve the same optimization model as above but on $G'=(V',E')$.

Comment: Can i use this condition for A_i's are not necessarily connected graph?

Comment: I don't see why not. Worst case scenario, there is no feasible solution.

Comment: SO, we can not get k non-disrupting path in the not necessarily connected graph. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, it is possible that this can happen. But you can figure out what is the highest number $l<k$ for which you can get an answer (in other words the $l$ non-disrupting  paths). Think about the max-flow problem.

Comment: I tried to use max-flow. It gives me maximum paths but it doesn't care about A_i which can use only once. How can i add constraint in max-flow that helps me to use A_i only one path.

Comment: You probably tried running maxflow on original graph $G$. You should run it on the transformed graph $G'$.

Comment: If i apply it in G' Where i see the problem is i have A_1 with nodes 1, 2, 3. 1 and 2 are connected but 3 is not connected with 1 and 2. I have path s-1-2-A_2 and s-3-A_3. If i create v' still i can get 2 paths from A_1.

Comment: That's not what I said in my answer. I said "for each node". That means that if you have $A_1=\{1,2,3\}$ then you create nodes $1',2',3'$ and your graph $G'$ has the arcs $(s,1), (1,1'),(1',2),(2,2'),(2',A_2), (s,3), (3,3'),(3',A_3),(A_2,t),(A_3,t),(t,s)$.